# Different view, models and controllers to each type of user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and C#.

I have 2 types of users are student and doctor the only difference between them doctor has edit, delete, add privileges to the tables in the SQL Server database.

I created a view, models and controllers for students, is it required to do different view, models and controllers for doctors? Or is there a way to edit  both student and doctor in a single set of views?

Comment: I think you confused users with entities.

Comment: Just use role based authentication to limit what the user can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use role based authentication in many ways to handle this (hide controllers , freeze controllers etc.) . but you should use login information to do it .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to consider about asp.net role based authorization.

[ASP.NET MVC 5: Role Based Accessibility](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc5-role-base-accessibility/)